# Unable to use typedarray in a custom view

Tags: android, typed-arrays

Following is my styelable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

  <declare-styleable name="MaterialIndicator">
    <attr name="mi_indicatorRadius" format="dimension|reference" />
    <attr name="mi_indicatorPadding" format="dimension|reference" />
    <attr name="mi_indicatorColor" format="color|reference" />
  </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

Im referring the above styelable as follows,

```
public MaterialIndicator(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        selectedIndicatorPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        indicatorPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        indicatorPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        indicatorPaint.setAlpha((int) (deselectedAlpha * 255));
        selectorRect = new RectF();
        if (isInEditMode()) {
            count = 3;
        }
        TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MaterialIndicator, 0, R.style.MaterialIndicator);
        try {
           selectedIndicatorPaint.setColor(typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.MaterialIndicator_mi_indicatorColor, 0));
        } finally {
            typedArray.recycle();
        }
    }
```

But it throws the following error message

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to
>   color: type=0x1
>                                                                                                      at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:339)

how can i be able to sort this out?

Comment: What happens if you remove `reference` from the xml file ?I mean you just have format="color"

Comment: still the same issue is persisting

Comment: Which line is 339 ?

Comment: TypedArray.java is the native android file

Comment: right. I think if you change it to : `          selectedIndicatorPaint.setColor(typedArray.getInteger(R.styleable.MaterialIndicator_mi_indicatorColor, 0));`  it should work.

Comment: Please see the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the source code [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/content/res/TypedArray.java#429)

`* @throws UnsupportedOperationException if the attribute is defined but is
*         not an integer color or color state list.`

Change color value :

```
           selectedIndicatorPaint.setColor(typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.MaterialIndicator_mi_indicatorColor, 0));
```

from zero to a color value. Where color value is :

`Color
A color value defined in XML. The color is specified with an RGB value and alpha channel. You can use a color resource any place that accepts a hexadecimal color value. You can also use a color resource when a drawable resource is expected in XML (for example, android:drawable="@color/green").`

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color

Edit : Something like `#80ff0000` should work

Comment: it works but im having color resource as ?android:attr/colorAccent hence it crashed

Comment: Where do you have `?android:attr/colorAccent ` ?

Comment: im having it in styles.xml

Comment: ok it works now... ?android:attr/colorAccent  is available only after SDK >= 21 so I changed it to @color/colorAccent ..it works fine now

Comment: Yeap that's exactly what I was going to tell you. Remove android namespace for <21. Glad it works!